# Hiding markers in Google Maps without Javascript

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, url, google-maps-static-api

So, I came here [via the Google mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-image-apis/MppSAw8qs5Y).

I'm trying to display a static map in a Qt application without using Javascript. So far I can get the right map specifying a center and a zoom level.

Now, I have two points and I want to fetch a map image that contains them and I managed to do it with markers.

Take this url as an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=satellite&size=800x1024&markers=size:small|color:white|loc:43.29377958,-7.49701604|loc:43.35536742,-7.48278365&sensor=false
```

This is the image I receive:

[image: Static map]

The white markers are clearly visible in the maps. I have [found a way to hide them via javascript](http://googlemapapitutorial.com/hidemarker.jsp) but I'm wondering if there's a way to specify it in the url directly, without using javascript.

While I found a way to get rid of the marker symbols (my answer), I would like to know if there's a better/proper way to achieve this.

Comment: Surely the simplest way would be to simply re-request the map through the url without the markers?

Comment: @Swires But in that case don't I need to specify a center and a zoom level?

Comment: Yes you would, I presumed you would have the location necessary for the centre point but I see now that's probably not the case. Setting the centre to the location of one of the markers would obviously cause a shift in the display... Unfortunately I only know the javascript API well so I'm perhaps not the best to answer this.

Comment: @Swires No worries! I have found a way!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fetch the same map without the marker symbols. Instead of using the `marker` label, I'm using the `visible` one.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=satellite&size=600x640&visible=loc:43.29377958,-7.49701604|loc:43.35536742,-7.48278365&sensor=false
```

This brings:

[image]

When I read the docs, I misunderstood it and thought it was a boolean value, so when I tried `visible=true` or `visible=false` I would lose the view of my map and the markers would still be there.