# Visible parameter provides too much margins

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

This is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460632/hiding-markers-in-google-maps-without-javascript).

I'm able to fetch the map for a bounding box (implicit positioning) thanks to the `visible` parameter but the returned map has too much margins. Quoting from the docs:

> the Static Maps API will determine a proper center and zoom level,
>   providing generous margins for the elements contained

This brings the map with a less zoom than if taken from a `wms`.

Is there a way to tell `Google Maps` to use smaller margins? Or not using margins at all?

**EDIT:** Knowing the "extension" of the margins provided will work too.